# New Ubuntu install v16.04 wireless not working

Tags: drivers, wireless

I am completely new to Linux but took the step of downloading Ubuntu because completely fed up with Windows.  Cannot get wireless working for Broadcom 14e4:4365 rev 01 - installed driver but ifconfig wlan0 up tells me no such device.  Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Please add the result of `lshw -C network`.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Negus but solved it as below - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

OK my problem is solved using the following steps:-

ctl alt t - to open terminal mode

update list of ubuntu PCI.IDs-     sudo update-pciids

build index of available packages -     sudo apt update

find installer for my card -     lspci -nn -d 14e4: (14e4 being code for broadcom wl card)

this recealed the pci id of my card as 14e4:4365 rev 01

based on my card id comparing it with the broadcom wireless table the correct package was bcmwl-kernel-source

then -     sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source

all then was ok

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I uninstalled default network manager and installed WICD network manager and that is working fine for me.

You can give a try .

To install WICD execute the commands:
1.

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

2. `sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk`
3. `sudo apt-get remove network-manager-gnome network-manager`

And then reboot the system .

Wifi should be working